# Get JSON response from iframe and save in database

Tags: php, html, json, forms, iframe

I have a form with file upload option. The action of the form is a 3rd party domain. I am uploading the file to another server. After upload success, I get a json response. How can I use those json response to save it in my database?

I don't have any control over the server i am uploading the file. I am just using a 3rd party service. they provide flash uploader. But i am working on a fallback(for apple handheld devices). If no flash, then i am using an iframe in which i am putting the form. this is my sample code:
**The main file**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="non-flash-upload.php"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**non-flash-upload.php**

```
<form action="some-3rd-party-domain" enctype="multipart/formdata">
  <input type="file" name="userfile" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When i submit this form, i get some json response with the information of uploaded file. these i want to save in my database. Is this possible? I tried with jquery to fetch them. but the iframe is going to some external domain and there it is printing the json response.
thanks a lot.

Comment: get the json_string in php variable and decode it in array as use as per your requirement.

Comment: Is there a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response?  Otherwise security restrictions prevent this.

Comment: @rajeev-ranjan - can you please explain a little bit more? thank you.

Comment: I dont see "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in the response. i cannot fetch the json with JS because it goes to another domain.